# Drupal changes my markup in full html mode

Tags: theming

While editing body of the node in Full HTML format, i enter these lines:

```
<div style="text-align:right">
    string 1<br />
    string 2<br />
    <br />
    string 3
</div>
```

But the real generated html is:

```
<div style="text-align:right">
    string 1
    <br>
    string 2
    <p>string 3</p>
</div>
```

What's wrong with that? Why Drupal changes my code in full html? I don't want any extra `<p>`'s because it breaks the layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the Full HTML format has the

> Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. `<br>` and `<p>`)

option selected. If you don't want that behaviour, just go to http://mysite.com/admin/config/content/formats/full_html and deselect that option:

[image]